# How is WITH used in Oracle SQL (example code shown )?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I found this example code online when I searched for "how to do an Exclusive Between oracle sql"

[Someone was proving that, in Oracle](https://community.oracle.com/thread/506412?start=0&tstart=0), `BETWEEN` is by default inclusive.

So they used such code :

```
with x as (
    select 1 col1 from dual
    union
    select 2 col1 from dual
    union
    select 3 col1 from dual
    UNION
    select 4 col1 from dual

 )

 select *
   from x
  where col1 between 2 and 3
```

I've never seen such an example, what is going on with the `WITH`  ?

Comment: It's called a common table expression. Search for that tag `[common-table-expression]` This  also documented in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2077142

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, WITH clause is an inline view, or subquery. It is useful when you will refer to something multiple times, or when you want to abstract parts of a complex query to make it easier to read.

If you are from SQL Server world, you can also think of it like a temporary table.

So:

```
WITH foo as (select * from tab);

select * from foo;
```

is like

```
select * from (select * from tab);
```

Though it may be more efficient since x is resolved to a single dataset, even if queried multiple times.

It also reduces repetition. If you use a subquery more than once in a statement, you can consider factoring it out using WITH.

It has nothing to do with the BETWEEN example, it is just the author's choice of approach for demonstrating a concept.